# How can you get gcc to fully vectorize this sqrt loop?

Tags: c++, gcc, x86, icc, auto-vectorization

If I take this code

```cpp
#include <cmath>

void compute_sqrt(const double* x, double* y, int n) {
  int i;
#pragma omp simd linear(i)
  for (i=0; i<n; ++i) {
    y[i] = std::sqrt(x[i]);
  }
}
```

and compile with `g++ -S -c -O3 -fopenmp-simd -march=cascadelake`, then I get instructions like this in the loop ([compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/dPjc4o))

```
...
  vsqrtsd %xmm0, %xmm0, %xmm0
...
```

XMMs are 128 bit registers but cascadelake supports avx-512. Is there a way to get gcc to use 256 (YMM) or 512 bit (ZMM) registers?

By comparison, ICC defaults to use 256 registers for cascadelake: Compiling with `icc -c -S -O3 -march=cascadelake -qopenmp-simd` produces ([compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/eoa4f9))

```
...
  vsqrtpd 32(%rdi,%r9,8), %ymm1 #7.12
...
```

and you can add the option `-qopt-zmm-usage=high` to use 512-bit registers ([compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/WWPG1s))

```
...
  vrsqrt14pd %zmm4, %zmm1 #7.12
...
```

Comment: Note that `vrsqrt14pd` is a fast approximate reciprocal, part of an approximation to sqrt that's faster if that's all you're doing in a loop (like your code).  In real life, do sqrt as part of some other computation so it can overlap with other ALUs being active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> XMMs are 128 bit registers

It's worse than that, `vsqrtsd` is not even a vector operation, as indicated by the `sd` on the end (scalar, double precision). XMM registers are also used by scalar floating point operations like that, but only the low 64 or 32 bits of the register contain useful data, the rest is zeroed out.

The missing options are `-fno-math-errno` (this flag is also implied by `-ffast-math`, which has additional effects) and (optionally) `-mprefer-vector-width=512`.

`-fno-math-errno` turns off setting `errno` for math operations, in particular for square roots this means a negative input results in NaN *without* setting `errno` to `EDOM`. ICC apparently does not care about that by default.

`-mprefer-vector-width=512` makes autovectorization prefer 512bit operations when they make sense. By default, 256bit operations are preferred, at least for `cascadelake` and `skylake-avx512` and other current processors, it probably won't stay that way for all future processors.

Comment: ICC defaults to `-fp-model fast=1`, somewhat like gcc / clang `-ffast-math` including I think treating FP math as associative.  So yeah, ICC doesn't give a rat's ass about setting `errno` by default!
[performance of icc main.cpp == g++ -ffast-math main.cpp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/20815).  That's why the OP sees it using `vrsqrt14pd`, a fast approximate reciprocal.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the `-ffast-math` flag, gcc will use YMM registers, e.g:

```
vsqrtpd (%rdi,%rax), %ymm0
vmovupd %ymm0, (%rcx,%rax)
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/GPfcbf)